# CameraPreview capture not returning result.value

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using Capacitor.Capture(CameraPreviewPictureOptions) but it's result.value is not valid, it is returning

`value: "data:," [[Prototype]]: Object`

I am implementing as

`const cameraPreviewPictureOptions: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = { quality: 90 }; const result = await CameraPreview.capture(cameraPreviewPictureOptions);`

Here output
`result.value is  'data:,'`

"@angular/core": "~13.2.2", "@capacitor/core": "^3.5.1", @ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0" , @capacitor-community/camera-preview": "^3.0.0"

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: Are you using las version of Ionic and Capacitor plugin?

Comment: "@angular/core": "~13.2.2", "@capacitor/core": "^3.5.1", @ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0" , @capacitor-community/camera-preview": "^3.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `CameraPreview.captureSample` instead of `CameraPreview.capture`